# Limit of sequences ($\lim x_n = a > 0 \Rightarrow \lim x_n ^{1/k} = a^{1/k}$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to show that if $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence such that $\lim x_n = a>0$, then $\lim \sqrt[k]{x_n} = \sqrt[k]{a}$.

It was suggest to use the equality $(x-a) = (x^{1/k} - a^{1/k})\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} x^{i/k} a^{-i + 1/k} \right)$ and I was thinking to use the definition to this proof (since I don't know yet what is $ \lim x_n^{p/q} $). But, if a get a particular $x_j$ such that $x_j <0$, if k is pair $x_j^{1/k}$ is not well defined in $\mathbb{R}$ and I don't know, in this case, if I can say that

$n \geq n_{\epsilon} \Rightarrow |x_n - a| < \epsilon \leq \epsilon.|\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(...)| $

So, what should I do, in this case? Change the proof to "eliminate" the problem or we must not consider this condition? I know that the sequence must have at least one positive number because it's limit is positive.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want the limit for large values of $n$, you can just start after all of the negative values of $x_n$.  Say for $n>N$.  But how can you be sure that the $x_n$ are (after a while) always positive?  Check the definition of *limit*.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It looks reasonable for me.But, how can I stricly say that we have always positive numbers after a while? I mean, it is kinda obvious, since we can get a really small $ \epsilon $ and a large value of n . But how to write it?

Answer (score 2):

You know that $\lim x_n = a > 0$. Take $\epsilon = \frac{a}{2} > 0$ in the $\epsilon/\delta$ definition of a limit: you can find $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|x_n-a| \leq \frac{a}{2}$.

Because of the triangle inequality, this implies $x_n \geq \frac{a}{2} > 0$ for $n \geq N$.

To conclude the exercise, notice that for every $n \geq N$, the suggested identity yields
$$
|x_n - a| \geq |\sqrt[k]{x_n}-\sqrt[k]{a}|\cdot a^{\frac{k-1}{k}}
$$
which provides an upper bound $|\sqrt[k]{x_n}-\sqrt[k]{a}| \leq C\, |x_n - a|$ with $C = a^{\frac{1-k}{k}} > 0$.